# git ignore all excel files but include one excel file, bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have below text in my `.gitignore` file, I want to exclude all excel files except one, means wants to push one excel file only,

Whitelist some files

```
!DBB/Tool Input.xlsx
```

Ignore All Files of below Type

```
*.xlsx
```

Let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `git check-ignore`?

Comment: @matt, "git check-ignore **/*" contains file "DBB/Tool Input.xlsx"

Comment: You did not show actual code, but what you have shown looks backward. First ignore all xlsx. Then unignore the one you want to keep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place them in the right order in your `.gitignore` file.

#### `.gitignore` is parsed from top to bottom and follow hierarchy:

1. Read the system ignore (if exist)
2. Read the global ignore (again if exist it should be under your home directory unless configured to point to a different location)
3. Read the project root `.gitignore`
4. Process (recursive) each folder `.gitignore` file

> **Note**
> Each step overwrite the previous one in case of "conflict" which means ambiguous rule

---

In your case, you can use it in different ways as explained above. The simplest way is to have it in your "root" `.gitignore` with the following content:

```sh
### This is the content of your .gitignore file
### -------------------------------------------

# Ignore All (xlsx) files
*.xlsx

# DO-NOT ignore specific file
!DBB/Tool Input.xlsx
```

---

**Option 2**

Yout "root" `.gitignore'

```
# Ignore All (xlsx) files
*.xlsx
```

Yout `.gitignore` inside the `DBB` folder

```
### do not ignore this specific file
!DBB/Tool Input.xlsx
```